# Totient maximum (project euler) - programm crashes

Tags: python, runtime

I'm trying to solve this excercise: https://projecteuler.net/problem=69. It works fine with the example given in the excercise, but it crashes when I try to calculate the maximum for n <= 1.000.000 and it is already pretty slow when I try to calculate it for n <= 5.000. How could I optimize my code? I'm using PyScripter.

```
def gcd(a, b):
  while b != 0:
    a, b = b, a % b
return a

def coprime(b):
  x = 0                # define a counter for the number of co-primes of b
  for a in range(1, b):
    if gcd(a, b) == 1: # check if a and b are co-prime
        x += 1         
return x

def main():
  maximum = 1
  for n in range(1, 1000001):
    m = coprime(n) 
    x = n / m           # calculate n/phi(n)
    if x > maximum:     # check if you have a new maximum
        maximum = n     
  print(maximum)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: Your algorithm is at least `O(n^2)`. For `n` a million it would require around a trillion calls to `gcd()`. You need a better, less brute-force, algorithm, perhaps something which is sieve-based.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to think about it!